# How do I add an icon for an Outlook Add-In?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook, icons, add-in

Because an outlook add-in is a DLL, not an EXE, Visual Studio does not let me change the icon for my assembly for the add-in. How can I associate an icon [and different size icons for the different view modes when looking at apps in the Control Panel] for my add-in so that it appears, for example, in "Programs and Features" in the Control Panel?

I'm using the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio 2010 to create my install set (setup.exe).

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching now for some time and I think the best way to add an Outlook icon is by creating a separate Setup Project for the Outlook Add-In. This way you have a much larger control of the setup process.